# Coroutines and Handlers

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, android-multithreading

I'm learning Coroutines in Android.
Here is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.buttonLoad.setOnClickListener {
            loadData()
        }
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        binding.progress.isVisible = true
        binding.buttonLoad.isEnabled = false
        loadCity { city ->
            binding.tvLocation.text = city
            binding.progress.isVisible = false
            binding.buttonLoad.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    private fun loadCity(callback: (String) -> Unit) {
        thread {
            Looper.prepare()
            val handler2 = Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            handler2.post {
                callback.invoke("London")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in loadCity fun I'm starting a new thread with looper and Handler and trying to run callback in it. At least app should crush. But no! There is only progress spinning and button disabled. NO crush, no response. Why?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with coroutines. Why are you expecting it to crash? The reason it doesn't do anything is that you never started your loop by calling `Looper.loop()`. But you can't loop in a thread and also use the same thread to do other stuff like sleep and post a callback into your loop. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: By the way, the two tags you used are very specific and followed by very few people, so barely anyone will see your question.